# How can I identify zero values, but format non-zero ones?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a column in an Excel spreadsheet that contains monetary values, most of which are zero. I want to hide the zero ones, but keep the non-zero ones formatted as currency.

[This Microsoft page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03) shows how to hide zeroes, but it leaves the non-zero values as integers. It doesn't explain how the tip works, so I can' see how to modify it to format what is shown.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Excel offers the choice of hiding zero values.

Take a squint at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found [the answer here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68). It seems that the semi-colons separate four sections of formatting, for positive numbers, negative numbers, zeroes and text.

In my case, I want currency shown for positive or negatives, and blank for zeroes, so the following custom format does the trick...

```
£#0.00;-£#0.00;
```

Because the third format is blank (ie there's nothing after the second semi-colon), it shows blank for zeroes, but uses the formatting in the first two otherwise.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: The # here has no effect.  It is interesting with a space like `£# 0` which tells Excel to separate thousands. (The proposed format are typically like `# ##0`, but just `# 0` does separate thousand too.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer Thanks for that. I was wondering what that was there for, but couldn't find a clear explanation

Answer (score 15):

A custom format like « `0;-0;` » tells Excel to print a normal number if positive (`0` format), normal number with a minus sign if negative (`-0` format), and nothing if null (the third part of the custom format).

You could have also fancy format (`0;-0;"NULL"`)… the order of format (positive;negative;null) is hardcoded in Excel.

Comment: I can't see how this part "keep the non-zero ones formatted as currency" is addressed in your answer

Comment: I was focusing on « how the tip works ». But, as you found, adding a £ does the job.