# How to hide ZERO values with a SUMIFS formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using the below formula to pull the accumulative monthly spend(fetched from individual order dates) based on postcode.

```
=SUMIFS(All!$E:$E,All!$A:$A,">="&Data!$A3,All!$A:$A,"<="&EOMONTH(Data!$A3,0),All!$D:$D,Data!B$2)
```

How do I incorporate a "hide £0.00" function into this formula?

Thanks!

Comment: What does Microsoft [**say about this**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03)?

Comment: Where are the "£0.00"'s and what do you want to "hide" them from? (selection criteria? , summed value?)

Comment: @JohnSUN Unfortunately i'm in an alternating coloured table so Conditional Formatting to white wouldn't look right, and the cells are already formatted for Currency so changing that might also have an adverse affect.

Comment: @DMM My £0.00 appear in my spend table, returned by the formula i'm using in each cell. I want the cell to remain blank if the spend returned is £0.00.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify zero values, but format non-zero ones?](https://superuser.com/questions/1698341/how-can-i-identify-zero-values-but-format-non-zero-ones)

Comment: On that page there is also a section "Display zeros as blanks or dashes". Yes, the formula will look terribly awkward, but this will do the trick: `=IF(SUMIFS(All!$E:$E,All!$A:$A,">="&Data!$A3,All!$A:$A,"<="&EOMONTH(Data!$A3,0),All!$D:$D,Data!B$2), "", SUMIFS(All!$E:$E,All!$A:$A,">="&Data!$A3,All!$A:$A,"<="&EOMONTH(Data!$A3,0),All!$D:$D,Data!B$2))`

Comment: @JohnSUN Thanks! After a bit of playing around i actually managed to re-write the Format to display the currency properly and also hide the zeroes, so all good!

Comment: @JohnSUN perhaps you want to add that as an answer. Please don't post an answer on comments.

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to hide them using the Format Cells function, with a Custom format of £0.00;-0;;@.

This maintains the currency format of the other cells that are not hidden.

Comment: So really a display issue and nothing to do with the `SUMIFS()` function at all.

Comment: @DMM Well if my formula wasn't so extensive i would have tried to put in an IF £0.00, display " ". Formatting was just an easier way of achieving that.

Comment: @hydrojack ... nice one you are getting +10,,, now I would like to suggest better use TEXT function along with existing formula like =`Text(Sumif(,,,,,,,, ), "£0.00;-0;;@")` or even `;;;` will work also ☺